# write text on image and show it to a imageview

Tags: android

i write text on a picture with this code :

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.file);
Canvas g = new Canvas(mBitmap);
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
p.setAntiAlias(true);
g.drawText("Text", 10, 10, p);
```

How can i show result in a imageview ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an ImageView (if you don't have one in your layout), and use `setImageDrawable()` :

```
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this); 
    image.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mBitmap));
```

Then add your ImageView to your layout with [addView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29).

Comment: Thanks But one question, my code to write text on picture is correct ? because when i run my program, my program give force close

Comment: It looks ok, do you have a stack trace when your program force closes?

Comment: Yes, problem is from `Canvas g = new Canvas(mBitmap);` but why, i dont know !

Comment: What's the exception thrown? It may be due to `BitmapFactory.decodeResource`, which returns null if it failed to load your bitmap.

Comment: Solved My Problem, only rename my file and refresh :) sorry, another question relate to it, how can use result to statusbar icon ? it's possible ?

Comment: Well you should create another question, because I don't know how to do. I think it's possible but don't know how, sorry.