# custom bitmap icon to Statusbar notification icon

Tags: android

my new question relate to my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280179/write-text-on-image-and-show-it-to-a-imageview)

i want create a custom bitmap and write a string on it and use it for StatusBar notification icon .

It's Possible, because `Battery Indicator Pro` exactly works with merging 2 image and show it on statusbar icon but how ?

can any one help to me ?

thanks

Comment: Have you read the docs?http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

> i want create a custom bitmap and write a string on it and use it for StatusBar notification icon .

This is not supported on Android 1.x and 2.x. For Android 3.x and above, there is `largeIcon`, which will be used when the notification drawer is open, but the regular icon is used when the drawer is closed.

> because Battery Indicator Pro exactly works with merging 2 image and show it on statusbar icon but how ?

The images in [the Market listing for that application](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.darshancomputing.BatteryIndicatorPro&hl=en) can be accomplished using ordinary resources.

Comment: i checked `Battery Indicator Pro` It using with layers, i think my problem solved with this trick, thanks for your answer .

Comment: Hi DAVOOD, can you describe more detail about the "layers trick"? I also needs the same feature!

Comment: Davood. can you explain the usage of layers to achieve using custom images for notification icon for pre Android 3.0

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any way to use a bitmap to appear in the status bar (not like the largeIcon).
I mangaged to convert the bitmap to a Drawable but setSmallIcon needs a resource id...

Comment: @RavitD: No, sorry, the small icon needs to be a resource.

Comment: What about the BigPictureStyle? Does it not show in the status bar?

Comment: @RavitD: The `Bitmaps` for `BigPictureStyle` are for the large icon (which you say is not what you want) and for the image shown in the expanded notification itself (which is not the small icon).

Comment: As I understand it, the only icon shown in the status bar is the small icon, right? 
Which means I have to use a resource id for it to appear in the status bar?
So all other icons only appear in the drop down menu. (This is what I saw when I used the setLargeIcon)

Comment: @RavitD: Correct on all counts.